# Why does connecting to a resource on the webserver take so long?

Tags: performance, firefox, networking, web

I am trying to analyze a site for performance issues. When I look in the Network panel in FireFox I see that some javascript files take a long time connecting to.

Here is an example:

[image: Performance]

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hitting your website with pagespeed plugin in chrome or run it on GTMetrix for performance analysis.
pagespeed will give similar breakdown as of above but in addition it will also give you suggestions for optimization.

In your case, javascript seems to be heavy. first thing you can do is minify your java script and then try again(this should resolve your problem). if it is again taking time then you need to work on logic used inside javascript. try to optimize that.

Pagespeed will give you minified version of your javascript and as well as other suggestions also.